# how to reverse index a 2-d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d MxN array A , each row of which is a sequence of indices, padded by -1's at the end e.g.:

```
[[ 2 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 4  3 -1 -1]
 [ 3 1  0 -1 -1]]
```

I have another MxN array of float values B:

```
[[ 0.7 0.4 1.5 2.0 4.4 ]
 [ 0.8 4.0  0.3 0.11 0.53]
 [ 0.6 7.4  0.22 0.71 0.06]]
```

and I want to use the indices in A to filter B i.e. for each row, only the indices present in A retain their values, and the values at all other locations are set to 0.0, i.e. the result would look like:

```
[[ 0.0 0.4 1.5 0.0 0.0 ]
 [ 0.0 4.0  0.0 0.11 0.53 ]
 [ 0.6 7.4  0.0 0.71 0.0]]
```

What's a good way to do this in "pure" numpy? (I would like to do this in pure numpy so I can [jit](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/02-jitting.html) it in jax.

Comment: You do realize that `-1` is a valid index in numpy? If not, please fix your question to indicate what you want done with -1s

Comment: why is the first value 2, in the index matrix, resulting in a value `0.0` in the output matrix?

Comment: When you present arrays, please post the code to initialize them, not the printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy supports fancy indexing. Ignoring the "-1" entries for the moment, you can do something like this:

```
index = (np.arange(B.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1), A)
result = np.zeros_like(B)
result[index] = B[index]
```

This works because indices are broadcasted. The column `np.arange(B.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)` matches all the elements of a given row of `A` to the corresponding row in `B` and `result`.

This example does not address the fact that `-1` is a valid numpy index. You need to clear the elements that correspond to `-1` in `A` when `4` (the last column) is not present in that row:

```
mask = (A == -1).any(axis=1) & (A != A.shape[1] - 1).all(axis=1)
result[mask, -1] = 0.0
```

Here, the mask is `[True, False, True]`, indicating that even though the second row has a `-1` in it, it also contains a `4`.

This approach is fairly efficient. It will create no more than a couple of boolean arrays of the same shape as `A` for the mask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting, but note that it will create a large intermediate array of shape `(M, N, N)` (in pure numpy at least):

```
import numpy as np

A = ...
B = ...

M, N = A.shape

out = np.where(np.any(A[..., None] == np.arange(N), axis=1), B, 0.0)
```

out:

```
array([[0.  , 0.4 , 1.5 , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 4.  , 0.  , 0.11, 0.53],
       [0.6 , 7.4 , 0.  , 0.71, 0.  ]])
```

Comment: You should use direct indexing (with broadcasting) instead of effectively trying to find unique elements.

Comment: Isn't finding unique indices to keep exactly what OP's expected output represents?

Comment: If you use `A` as an index, you don't need to find the unique indices explicitly

Comment: Ive checked out your answer and I see what you mean. Indeed that is a lot more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
maxr = np.max(A, axis=1)
A = np.where(A == -1, maxr.reshape(-1,1), A)
mask = np.zeros(np.shape(B), dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask, A, True, axis=1) 
np.where(mask, B, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.  , 0.4 , 1.5 , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 4.  , 0.  , 0.11, 0.53],
       [0.6 , 7.4 , 0.  , 0.71, 0.  ]])
```

---

**EDIT (When there is rows with only -1)**

The following code aims to contemplate the possibility, raised by @MadPhysicist (to whom I thank), of having rows containing only -1 -- that is only necessary to add 2 lines of code to my previous code.

```
A = np.array([[ 2, 1, -1, -1, -1],
              [ -1, -1,  -1, -1, -1],
              [ 3, 1,  0, -1, -1]])

B = np.array([[ 0.7, 0.4, 1.5, 2.0, 4.4 ],
              [ 0.8, 4.0,  0.3, 0.11, 0.53],
              [ 0.6, 7.4,  0.22, 0.71, 0.06]])

rminus1 = np.all(A == -1, axis=1) # new
maxr = np.max(A, axis=1)
A = np.where(A == -1, maxr.reshape(-1,1), A)
mask = np.zeros(np.shape(B), dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask, A, True, axis=1) 
C = np.where(mask, B, 0)
C[rminus1, :] = 0 # new
```

Output:

```
array([[0.  , 0.4 , 1.5 , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.6 , 7.4 , 0.  , 0.71, 0.  ]])
```

Comment: What if the entire row is -1?

Comment: Thanks for commenting my solution, @MadPhysicist. I do not believe such a case can occur, as the OP writes _"each row of which is a sequence of indices, padded by -1's"_, which expresses certainty about the existence of at least one index.

Comment: While I don't read it that way, it's a totally valid interpretation

Comment: I did not think much about how to accommodate that possibility in my code, but I suspect it should be more or less trivial.

Comment: I have just added a new solution that works also when there is rows with only -1, @MadPhysicist. Thanks again!